# Extend the res.user to link with categories created by the specific user

Tags: python, xml, odoo, odoo-11

Extend the pos.category form with inherited view, How can I append a smart button at first part of the form with xpath

```
 <record id="view_pos_category_inherited_form" model="ir.ui.view">
    <field name="name">view.pos_category.inherited.form</field>
    <field name="model">pos.category</field>
     <field name="inherit_id" ref="point_of_sale.product_pos_category_form_view" />
    <field name="arch" type="xml">

    <xpath expr="//form" position="inside">
            <sheet>
                <header>
                        <button class="oe_stat_button" name="" icon="fa-th-list" type="action" context="{'search_default_create_uid': uid}">
                        <div class="o_field_widget o_stat_info">
                            <span class="o_stat_value"><field name="user_categories_count"/></span>
                            <span class="o_stat_text"> Categories</span>
                        </div>      
                    </button>
                </header>
            </sheet>

    </xpath>


    </field>


</record>
```

Comment: Look at how it is done elsewhere, such as on the sales order form view. Usually you will need to place it at the begin of the form, like before an `h1` (depends on the form structure). If you place `inside` the form then it will be placed at the bottom.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do not add `<sheet>` tag before `<header>` tag. Just code like hit

```
<xpath>
<header></header>
<sheet></sheet>
</xpath>
```

Your xpath is correct just done this change and it will work